#  How can we evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt$ without using Laplace transforms?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Without using Laplace transforms, how do I show that for every positive number $x$ the following equation is valid? $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt=\frac{1}{x^2+1}. $$

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like a classic case for expanding the sine using Euler's formula.

Comment: @Gardel: Generally speaking, it is a good idea to avoid (i) displayed equations in the title; and (ii) titles that consist entirely of $\LaTeX$. This has to do with the way they are displayed and handled by the site, as well as issues with searches.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: You're right. There is nothing to do after using Euler's formula. Thank you!

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin: Thanks, I'm starting to use the forum and therefore need that kind of information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yet another one (particularly useful when evaluating **particular integral** of ODE):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}\sin t\ dt&=\Im\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}e^{it}\ dt\right]\\
&=\Im\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-i)t}\ dt\right]\\
&=\Im\left[\frac1{x-i}\right]\\
&=\Im\left[\frac1{x-i}\cdot\frac{x+i}{x+i}\right]\\
&=\frac1{x^2+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Please note that same approach can be applied to get integral involving $\sin mt$, $\cos mt$ etc.

Comment: This is really amazing, thank you...

Answer (score 7):

$\rm\bf Hint$:
$$\large e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)\implies \sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}.$$

Comment: yes, now I see. Thank you!

Comment: @anon: So, $\sint$ = imaginary part of $e^{it}$ simplifies things better.

Answer (score 6):

Why the "complex analysis" tag? It's just a double integration:

$$
\int e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt=-\frac{1}{x}e^{-xt}\sin(t)+\frac{1}{x}\int e^{-xt}\cos(t)dt=
$$

$$
=-\frac{1}{x}e^{-xt}\sin(t)-\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-xt}\cos(t)-\frac{1}{x^2}\int e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt
$$

It follows that

$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\int e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt= -\frac{1}{x}e^{-xt}\sin(t)-\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-xt}\cos(t)+
$$

It follows that

$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt= \frac{1}{x^2}
$$

$$
\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}\right)\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt= \frac{1}{x^2}
$$

$$
 \int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\sin(t)dt= \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
It follows that the integral is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, as you wrote.

Comment: When you find d(cos(t)) in the second line it has a minus sign, so the last term has the wrong sign.  Please put the $dt$'s in as well

Comment: thank you for finding the typo.

Answer (score 4):

If you integrate by parts twice, using $u=\exp(-xt), dv=\sin(t)dt$ then $dv= \cos(t)dt$ you get the same integral back and can solve for it.